# Large numpy matrix memory issues

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, memory-management

I have two questions, but the first takes precedence.

I was doing some timeit testing of some basic numpy operations that will be relevant to me.

I did the following

```
n = 5000
j = defaultdict()
for i in xrange(n):
    print i
    j[i] = np.eye(n)
```

What happened is, python's memory use almost immediately shot up to 6gigs, which is over 90% of my memory.  However, numbers printed off at a steady pace, about 10-20 per second.  While numbers printed off, memory use sporadically bounced down to ~4 gigs, and back up to 5, back down to 4, up to 6, down to 4.5, etc etc.
At 1350 iterations I had a segmentation fault.

So my question is, what was actually occurring during this time?  Are these matrices actually created one at a time?  Why is memory use spiking up and down?

My second question is, I may actually need to do something like this in a program I am working on.  I will be doing basic arithmetic and comparisons between many large matrices, in a loop.  These matrices will sometimes, but rarely, be dense.  They will often be sparse.

If I actually need 5000 5000x5000 matrices, is that feasible with 6 gigs of memory?  I don't know what can be done with all the tools and tricks available...  Maybe I would just have to store some of them on disk and pull them out in chunks?

Any advice for if I have to loop through many matrices and do basic arithmetic between them?

Thank you.

Comment: If they will usually be sparse, the solution is pretty simple: use [sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) objects. The occasional dense ones will be a tiny bit larger, but the sparse ones will be orders of magnitude smaller, which will vastly more than make up for the difference.

Comment: Are you doing pairwise comparisons of these matrices? It might help if you explain a little what you're doing with these, in case there are less memory-intensive ways to solve your problem.

Comment: Doesn’t address your memory issue, but run matrix operations on the GPU and watch your work speed up significantly

Comment: The matrices represent traversals of graphs over time. I don't really want to get to into it.. but the operations I will be doing are row-wise comparisons, MxN unions (doing the union... not sum, of M rows), and then also doing the sum of M rows.

Comment: Are you talking about operations within each matrix, separately, or operations across many matrices?

Comment: in every case it will be an operation between any given pair of matrices, resulting in one of them being modified, or in the creation of a new matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I actually need 5000 5000x5000 matrices, is that feasible with 6 gigs of memory?

If they're dense matrices, and you need them all at the same time, not by a long shot. Consider:

```
5K * 5K = 25M cells
25M * 8B = 200MB (assuming float64)
5K * 200MB = 1TB
```

---

The matrices are being created one at a time. As you get near 6GB, what happens depends on your platform. It might start swapping to disk, slowing your system to a crawl. There might be a fixed-size or max-size swap, so eventually it runs out of memory anyway. It may make assumptions about how you're going to use the memory, guessing that there will always be room to fit your actual working set at any given moment into memory, only to segfault when it discovers it can't. But the one thing it isn't going to do is just work efficiently.

---

You say that most of your matrices are sparse. In that case, use one of the [sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) representations. If you know which of the 5000 will be dense, you can mix and match dense and sparse matrices, but if not, just use the same sparse matrix type for everything. If this means your occasional dense matrices take 210MB instead of 200MB, but all the rest of your matrices take 1MB instead of 200MB, that's more than worthwhile as a tradeoff.

---

Also, do you actually need to work on all 5000 matrices at once? If you only need, say, the current matrix and the previous one at each step, you can generate them on the fly (or read from disk on the fly), and you only need 400MB instead of 1TB.

---

Worst-case scenario, you can effectively swap things manually, with some kind of caching discipline, like least-recently-used. You can easily keep, say, the last 16 matrices in memory. Keep a dirty flag on each so you know whether you have to save it when flushing it to make room for another matrix. That's about as tricky as it's going to get.